# atoi does not seem to be working for my program

Tags: c, error-handling, char, atoi

here is a simple program for postfix calculator using stack, but the atoi() causes it to crash. Why is it happening? 
I have tried converting the char to string using ch-'0' and it works but the atoi() function for char to int conversion does not seem to work in this case.

Is it because ch is a char nor string 
eg. char ch; and not char ch[20];

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 100
int num[MAX],tos=-1;

push(int x)
{
    if(tos==MAX)
    {
        printf("the stack is full");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("  l");
        tos++;
        num[tos]=x;
    }
}
int pop()
{
    if(tos<0)
    {
        printf("stack underflow");
    }
    else
    return num[tos--];
}
int main()
{
    char postfix[MAX],exp[MAX],ch,val;
    int a,b;
    printf("enter the postfix expression");
    fgets(postfix,MAX,stdin);
    strcpy(exp,postfix);
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(postfix);i++)
    {
         printf(" xox ");
        ch=postfix[i];
        if(isdigit(ch))
        {
            push(ch - '0');
            printf(" %d ",atoi(ch));
        }
      else
      {
          printf("%d",tos);
          a=pop();
          b=pop();
          switch(ch)
          {
          case '+':
            val=a+b;
            break;
          case '-':
            val=a-b;
            break;
          case '*':
            val=a*b;
            break;
          case '/':
            val=a/b;
            break;
        }
        printf("%d",val);
        push(val);
      }
    }
    printf("the result of the expression %s = %d",exp,num[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"Is it because ch is a char nor string eg. char ch; and not char ch[20];"* That's right. It works on strings and there's no overload for just a single `char`.

Comment: so using atoi() function possible in anyway @Blaze and what do you mean by overload?

Comment: If you want to transform a `char` that represents a number from 0 to 9 to the respective integer, simply subtract `'0'` like you're already doing in your code. If you want it to keep the same value (so for instance  `'0'` is `48` in ASCII), just assign the char to the int variable.

Comment: `atoi(ch)` shouldn't even compile. Your compiler is either terribly bad or it is not configured correctly.

Comment: Add `default: printf("<%d>\n", ch);` to see a problem.

Comment: Compile with all warnings enabled and treat them as errors, especially the warning displayed at the line containing `atoi`. Hint: `atoi` expects a pointer to a string, but you're passing a `char`. You're mixung up strings and chars, read the chapter dealing with strings in your C text book.

Comment: `if(tos==MAX)` test is off by 1.

Comment: You pass a `char` where a `char*` is expected. The documentation to `atoi()` should have told you that and the compiler should have warned you.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it because ch is a char nor string eg. char ch; and not char ch[20];

Yes. `atoi(ch)` is not even valid C and is not allowed to compile cleanly.

In this case you can create a temporary string based on `ch` and a null terminator. For example through a compound literal: `(char[2]){ch, '\0'}`.

And you should never use `atoi` for any purpose, since it has poor error handling and is a completely superfluous function. Use the `strtol` family of functions instead.

You can call `strtol` like this:

```
strtol( (char[2]){ch, '\0'}, // string to convert from
        NULL,                // end pointer, not used, set to NULL
        10 );                // base 10 = decimal
```

Example:

```
printf(" %d ", (int)strtol( (char[2]){ch, '\0'}, NULL, 10) );
```

Which is completely equivalent to the more readable:

```
char tmp[2] = { ch, '\0' };
int result = (int) strtol(tmp, NULL, 10);
printf(" %d ", result);
```